# Is it possible to reverse the default column/row assignments when selecting data for an Excel "XY" scatter chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When selecting data for use in an Excel scatter chart the default column/row assignments are that the first column/row will be used for the X axis and subsequent columns/rows will be used for the Y axis. For example, if there are five columns of data selected, the first column is the X axis and columns two, three, four, and five are the Y axis (series 1, series 2, series 3 and series 4). Is it possible to reverse the default assignment so the first column is the Y axis and subsequent columns are used for the X axis? So for five columns, the first column is the Y axis and columns two, three, four, and five are the X axis (series 1, series 2, series 3 and series 4).

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to create a chart from the data layout you describe. There is no switch you can set in Excel to use the first column as the Y value and the second and following columns as X values. You can insert an empty XY chart and then manually add the data series. The data layout with the Y in the first column is so unusual that it took a lot of concentration to get the chart right. 
I'd prefer to re-arrange the data to follow Excel's logic of the data layout rather than work against Excel.
The screenshot shows a chart that can be manually stitched together by defining each series by hand, or, using the lower data layout, with one click.
[image: XY chart]

Comment: Thanks for looking into my question, I have been manually adjusting the data with good results. I was hoping I could switch the default as that would save me a considerable ammount of time. Thanks again for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is.
I have Excel 2000. I right click on the chart, click `source data` (translated) then there's `Series in` and a radio button to select either `rows` or `columns`

Comment: Unfortunatly, this only switches whether the selected data is input as columns or rows. In either case the default is still to use the first column\row as the X axis. I wanted the first column\row to be the Y axis with multiple X axis series. Thanks anyway, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Kitet may have been partly right](https://superuser.com/a/543661/150988). 
Is *this* the sort of thing you want?

[image]

I started out small and did this:

[image]

by entering the data, creating the chart, right-clicking on the curve, and selecting “Select Data…”:

[image]

That gave me this “Select Data Source” pop-up:

[image]

where I clicked on “Edit”.  That gave me the “Edit Series” dialog box, and I just changed all the `A`s to `B`s and vice versa:

[image]

The one with the two `X` series was the same, except, in the “Select Data Source” pop-up, you will need to click on each series and “Edit” each one.

This is on Excel 2007.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,yes, this is how I have been able to make charts of this type. However, manually changing the data in the "Edit Series" dialog boxes is quite time consuming (especially if there are a lot of columns). If there were some way to tell Excel to use the first column of the selected data as the Y axis it would be a real time saver, this is what I am trying to find out.